# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre las palabras "viajador" y "viajero"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Obviamente son sinónimos, pero me gustaría saber exactamente en cual contexto uno se usa más que el otro.
Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según el diccionario [viajero](https://dle.rae.es/viajero?m=form) y [viajador](https://dle.rae.es/viajador?m=form) son adjetivos sinónimos; ambos designan

> a quien viaja

Sin embargo en el uso coloquial hay un matiz que quizás muchos comprendan: **viajador** es como se calificaría a quien tiene el hábito de hacerlo frecuentemente.

Así, supongamos que dos persona compartan asientos en un vuelo fuera de su país: a ambos les cabría igualmente la denominación de "viajeros". Pero, si uno de ellos lo hace por primera vez, mientras que el otro repite esa experiencia que vivió numerosas veces, sólo a éste último le correspondería el calificativo de "viajador".

> *¿Sabías que me encontré con Fulano en el avión cuando fui por primera vez a tal lugar?*
>
> — *Ah, si, no es nada raro, es muy **viajador***

En la literatura, se encuentra su uso también con esa connotación; van dos ejemplos:

- En *Lluvia de Vida* de Ricardo García Ortiz_Villajos, se lee la biografía del autor.

> *Madrileño de 1963 , aunque muy **viajador** y observador del mundo que le rodea. Espero que disfruten. de ste adulto . Nacido en Madrid en Julio de 1963. De sólida formación técnica y finalmente reside en el popular barrio del Retiro.*

- En "El trabajoso camino del agua", de Marta Nos, se lee

> *... porque había visto pasar a Angel Miguel Bodegas desde la barbería y a Vicente Campomanes desde el club y sociedad de fomento , y hasta el viejo Sandoval , arrimadizo y putero y en esa época muy **viajador** , que aún hoy , aún ayer digo ...*

Answer (score 5):

A pesar de que ambas palabras están en el diccionario, nunca había visto usar *viajador* hasta ahora. Google confirma la rareza:

- *Viajador*: 56.700 resultados
- *Viajero*: 40.400.000 resultados

Respondiendo a la pregunta de *en qué contexto se usa más*, me atrevo a decir que, posiblemente, en ninguno.

Otro sinónimo es *viajante* (11.300.000 resultados según Google) que sí tiene un significado adicional más específico, como la persona que viaja por su actividad comercial.

Answer (score 2):

Ambas palabras son adjetivos y también son usadas como sustantivos. Pero en el uso como sustantivo se usa más "viajero", además también esta palabra puede referirse a alguien que relata un viaje.

Answer (score 0):

Viajador es un adjetivo.
Viajero es adjetivo y nombre. Cómo nombre se utiliza para describir a la persona que viaja.
Viajante es nombre y adjetivo, pero como nombre se refiere a los comerciales cuyo trabajo consiste en viajar de un sitio a otro.